# coldfusion cffile upload passing a parameter to the action page

Tags: parameters, coldfusion, upload, cffile

In coldfusion I have a basic cffile upload which works fine when the nameconflict parameter is explicit, such as 'overwrite'.  But when I try to pass a parameter, it doesn't work.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset confl = 'overWrite'>
<form 
  enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
  method  = "post" 
  name    = "uploadForm"  
  action  = "">

   <input name  = "theupload" 
          type  = "file" 
          style = "font-family: comic sans ms; color: ##679C9C">

  <input type = 'hidden' name = 'confl' value = '#confl#'>   
  <cfinclude template = 'submitbut.cfm'>
  </form>
  </cfoutput> 

  <cfif IsDefined("form.theupload")>
  <cfoutput>
   <cffile action = "upload"
    destination   = "#session.exploc#"
    fileField     = "form.theupload"        
    mode          = '666'
    result        = 'ss'
    nameConflict  = "#form.confl#" >

   </cfoutput>
   </cfif>
```

Is this just the nature of cffile upload?  Is there a way to pass a parameter to the action page?  The above code is used in several places, and I don't always want the name conflict to be 'overwrite'.  I hate to have to use two programs when the only difference is in the name conflict.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? What "doesn't work"? What behaviour were you expecting, and how did the actual behaviour vary from that? Might be useful to read: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: If you dump the form scope do you see the `confl` value?

Comment: @DanBracuk.  I did a cfoutput on the confl value before the input hidden statement and got the right number.  I did it again after the isdefined form.upload statement and got a blank. I didn't dump the form scope but will try that next.

Comment: @DanBracuk.  I set up a temporary cfm which had the main features in it.  When I dumped the form scope everything was all right, and when I tried to substitute my form variable for the name conflict field that also worked.  The program I showed in my question is included in a larger program which also has a form, and I think cf got tangled in its skirts as to which form was meant where.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm certainly willing to give these forms different names.  But strangely, I don't know how to specify which form to use on the action page.  Do I replace <cfset x = form.something> with <cfset x = form.formname.something?  Or what?  I can't find this mentioned anywhere.

Comment: If you really need more than one form on a page and they are all posting to the same action page, the action page has to know what form was submitted.  I suggest hidden fields such as `fom1`, `form2`, etc.

Comment: @DanBracuk -- not sure what you mean. I do use hidden fields, but how does that distinguish the different forms.   I can give each form a name, but I don't know how to reference that name on the action page.   Right now I'm trying to do it by using window.open() on the uploads, which would eliminate the double form problem.  And maybe present other problems but I'm not there yet.

Answer (score -2):

1. Wrap the `<cffile>` in a function inside a CFC.
2. Make all of the variables arguments of the function.
3. Create the CFC (or put it in the `application` scope).
4. Call the function with the settings correct for each form.

Inside the CFC, do NOT reference `session`, `form`, `application`, `request` or any other external scoped variables. Only pass data in as arguments to the function. Also, make sure to `var` or `local` scope all function specific variables.

Comment: Mine is the second downvote.  I don't see how this answer solves the OP's problem.  Feel free to explain it though.

Comment: True it doesn't answer the initial question, but it does address the latter issue of wanting to avoid repeating the same code in multiple places.